# A problem about colimits and the Yoneda functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, limits-colimits, yoneda-lemma

I encountered a problem when I was reading Chapter Two of the book [Categories and sheaves](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/kashiwara2.pdf).

In this book, for $\alpha:I\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$, the colimit $\lim\limits_\rightarrow\alpha$ is defined as a functor $ X\mapsto \lim\limits_\leftarrow Hom_\mathcal{C}(\alpha,X)$. Let $k$ be the Yoneda functor $X\mapsto Hom_\mathcal{C}(X,-)$.

Then by Yoneda's lemma, on the one hand,
we have
$$
\begin{align}
(\lim\limits_\rightarrow\alpha)(X)&=\lim\limits_\leftarrow Hom_\mathcal{C}(\alpha,X)=\lim\limits_\leftarrow Hom_\mathcal{C^*}(k(\alpha),k(X)) \\
&=Hom_\mathcal{C^*}(\lim\limits_\rightarrow k(\alpha),k(X))=(\lim\limits_\rightarrow k(\alpha))(X)\\
&=\lim\limits_\rightarrow [k(\alpha)(X)]
\end{align}
$$

since colimits exist in $\mathcal{C^*}:=Fun(\mathcal{C}\rightarrow Set)$. The last equality is by Proposition 2.1.6.

One the other hand, however,
$$
\begin{align}
(\lim\limits_\rightarrow\alpha)(X)&=\lim\limits_\leftarrow Hom_\mathcal{C}(\alpha,X)=\lim\limits_\leftarrow [k(\alpha)(X)] 
\end{align}
$$
by the definition of $k$. Could anyone tell me where is the mistake? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that they define $\mathcal C^\ast$ as the opposite category of what you have. Only then $k$ becomes covariant and only then the equality $\hom(\alpha, X)=\hom(k\alpha, k(X))$ holds. But then the colimit in the end is actually a limit in the category of sets, and both calculations will agree on the outcome.

Comment: I would rather (but equivalently) say that $k$ is a functor from the opposite category and so there'd be an extra equality that turns $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(\alpha,X)$ into $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^{op}}(X,\alpha)$.

Comment: That is another possibility, however in the book the OP refers to they chose to do it as I wrote, so I thought it is best to stick to their conventions.